# Collections sort - Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

i have this code working perfectly fine on netbeans 8, but i can't seem to compile it with javac. It gives 2 errors:

[image]

I have the following imports:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
```

EDIT: Forgot to add -> Ponto and Percursos are inner classes. ListaPercursos and ListaPontos are ArrayList of those classes.

Comment: Try running `javac -version` to check its version.

Comment: vcoder@laptop ~/Desktop/t $ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_51

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`List#sort(Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) was added in Java 8. It seems you have a Java 7 compiler. You'll need to [upgrade](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Comment: D= i have to make this work with Java 7. Any sugestions?

Comment: @Vcoder Use `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`. The method you are trying to use doesn't exist in Java 7.